# Have I damaged my camera's sensor?

Tags: canon, dslr, sensor

Excuse the image of the random cat, but I noticed these random purple spots/lines in all the pictures I've taken today. They're in the same location and in the same shape so have I damaged the sensor?

[image]

Comment: What exact model? The odd thing is, grunge on the sensor usually only looks sharply defined at f/11 or above while the picture certainly looks very unlike one taken at f/11 or above :) Unless it is ACTUAL sensor damage (as opposed to scratches in the sensor filter), eg by focused sunlight, laser, manufacturing defects...

Comment: Canon 200d. It was taken at f1.8  @ 1/125 sec ISO 100. I've had this for 5 months and this is the first time its happened.

Comment: I'm not sure actually. I just mentioned me possibly damaging the sensor because it's been stored in a room for about 2 weeks, temperature was cool and placed within its bag. So I'm not sure how it could've been damaged.

Comment: There have been previous questions here with examples that demonstrate the same characteristics. So far, I don't think anyone has come up with an obvious explanation.

Comment: Two questions: First, have you checked for water spots on the back of the lens?  Second, do these show up in RAW or only in JPEG?  (I doubt this is a weird out-of-gamut/truncation bug, but you never know.)

Comment: No water spots and its appearing in both. I mostly shoot images in RAW. The peculiar thing is that almost all the most have remained in their positions except the ones of the top left which I believe have shifted to the bottom left in a slightly different orientation. I've cleaned the lens with both dry and wet methods, no difference. Guess will learn to live with it. Kind of sad since this was my first purchase of a camera.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like green sensels have gone dark. Lasers can cause damage like this.

- ILDA: [Laser damage to cameras](https://ilda.com/camera-sensor-damage.htm)
- Gizmodo: [Laser Light Show Burns a DSLR Sensor](https://gizmodo.com/laser-light-show-burns-a-dslr-sensor-5596508)

Comment: It hasn't been exposed to any laser light so not sure that's the reason. I shoot in the mornings and indoors at that. And it wasn't in use for 2 weeks where again, no lasers or direct exposed light.

Comment: If it ain't radiation damage of some sort, the only likely explanation short of an electronic defect is crud that found its way *below* the IR/AA filter ... ouch.

Comment: ...or ESD damage, possibly? Would be extra ouch...